# PHP comparing multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to compare two arrays and take data from Array2 and put it in Array1 if the corresponding index in Array1 is empty.  Here's an example of the arrays.  The second array has data that the first array does not.

```
Array(
    [Customer] => Array(
        [sales_associate] => 
        [store] => 
    )
    [CustomerPersonalInformation] => Array(
        [first_name] => FirstName 
        [middle_initial] => 
        [last_name] => Lastname
        [gender] => 
    )
    [CustomerContactInformation] => Array(
        [primary_phone] => (111)111-1111
        [email] => email@gmail.com
        [street_address] => 
        [city] => 
        [state] => 
        [zip] => 
        [county] => 
    )
    [Marketing] => Array(
        [accepts_calls] => 
        [accepts_emails] => 
        [best_contact_time] => 
    )
)
Array(
    [Customer] => Array(
        [sales_associate] => Me
        [store] => There
    )
    [CustomerPersonalInformation] => Array(
        [first_name] => FirstName 
        [middle_initial] => E
        [last_name] => Lastname
        [gender] => 
    )
    [CustomerContactInformation] => Array(
        [primary_phone] => (111)111-1111
        [email] => email@gmail.com
        [street_address] => 
        [city] => 
        [state] => 
        [zip] => 
        [county] => 
    )
    [Marketing] => Array(
        [accepts_calls] => 
        [accepts_emails] => 
        [best_contact_time] => 
    )
)
```

I can't think of how to loop through the arrays since the indices aren't numbers.  I know I have to use foreach loops, but I can't seem to get my head around it.  Here's the last thing I tried (unsuccessfully):

```
foreach($firstArray as $element) {
    foreach($element as $value) {
        echo $value;
        echo $secondArray[$element][$value];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @AmalMurali  I would expect it to be every element of each array.  But it only works on Array1

Comment: Have you looked at array_replace_recursive()?

Comment: @user1179374: I don't understand what you mean. Could you add the expected `print_r()` output of the new array to the question?

Comment: @AmalMurali  Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  In this specific case, it should make the first array be identical to the second one.  The second one has data in 3 places where there's nothing in the first.

Comment: @user1179374: You haven't answered my question. But ignore that, see the reply from @-Jack above. Good luck!

Comment: @Jack That looks like it would work in this case, but I don't want it to replace any existing data, just fill empty elements with the corresponding element in Array2.  "If the key exists in the second array, and not the first, it will be created in the first array. If a key only exists in the first array, it will be left as is."  This part is exactly what I want, just not the first part of the function.

Comment: @AmalMurali I didn't really have any expected output because I hadn't written the comparison part yet, so I wasn't sure how to answer.  I just wanted to know how to loop through these specific arrays because what I had wasn't working. Probably should have worded the question differently, I was getting ahead of myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop thru the second array and check if the element is present in the first array like this:

```
foreach($secondArray as $elementKey => $elementContent) {
    if(! isset($firstArray[$elementKey]) || empty($firstArray[$elementKey])) {
        $firstArray[$elementKey] = $elementContent;
    }
    foreach($elementContent as $ecKey => $ecValue) {
        if(! isset($firstArray[$elementKey][$ecKey]) || empty($firstArray[$elementKey][$ecKey])) {
            $firstArray[$elementKey][$ecKey] = $ecValue;
        }
    }
}
```